# How can I modify the Upland PowerSteering templates for Iterative/Agile Management?

Tags: agile, planning

Our department recently brought in Power Steering for waterfall projects but in the absence of an agile-focused software (Jira, Rally, VersionOne) there is some appetite to experiment with Power Steering for agile projects.

At present the tool is set up to Gate waterfall projects with a number of templates.  Is it possible to modify the templates to reflect the needs of an iterative project; if so, how is this done?

Very little *good* documentation exists online and the Upland guides are pretty spartan to be honest so am hoping the SE community has tinkered with it and found a solution.

Comment: What do you want to know about this tool?

Comment: Well, let's start with the actual question.  Has anyone used it for iterative management?  I don't consider the question unclear in any way.

Comment: Hi @Venture2099. Questions on Stack Exchange should be about a real, actual problem you're facing, asked in Q&A format. We're not an open-ended discussion forum. Asking if anyone has used it is a simple yes/no question that doesn't help anyone solve a problem. Instead, can you please explain, in an edit to your post, what problem you're looking to solve? As Sklivvz asked, what do you want to know *about this tool?*  See [ask] and [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) for more guidance on rewording this post. Hope this helps!

Comment: As an aside, when you edit the post, it will get bumped back up for review, where the community can vote to reopen and take it off-hold. Additionally, a moderator can do that as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that @jmort253 - I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Venture2099 - Thanks for editing. I think this fixes our concerns and will also help you get the best answers possible, so I'll reopen this for answers. Good luck and hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, **this is not possible**. The good news is, using software is optional when it comes to agile methodologies and frameworks. If you must use a tool, try www.trello.com; its the only free agile board for unlimited users AFAIK.

Side note: I don't understand why would your department buy a non-agile software and then ask you to experiment with it? It sounds like a waste of time.

Comment: I just realized this is a very old post. The answer holds true though.